# How to break operators,identifiers,string etc from text file in c# without using split

Tags: c#

I am making a lexical analyzer for compiler contruction course using c#.
I am taking input from a notepad file. 
Please tell me how can I break datatypes,operators,identifier etc from that text file and save those broken words in array or list.
Then I will validate those words through Dfa's of identifeir,data types etc after that I will generate tokens.

This is my foreach loop in which I want to pass those words from array or list.

```
//x will be string of datatypes,keyword,identifiers etc of my language.
//richTextBox1.Lines will be replaced by that array or list which I will create.
foreach (string x in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    //code for validating
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is construct an Expression Tree from a set of text. I can't give you a complete answer (because your question is about a technique, not a technical problem) but if you look through this link on Expression Trees in .net and then research other Expression Tree building libraries in .net (there is a built-in C# parser, a Microsoft T-SQL parser available) then this will give you a good starting point.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx